# Как вывести целиком JSON объект?

Tags: node.js

arr = массив объектов, получаемый асинхронно! Как сделать, чтобы при обновлении (localhost:3000/products) сразу видеть полный массив объектов, а то я его вижу постепенно наполняющимся... Спасибо!

```
import express from 'express';
import { arr } from './index.js';

const app = express();
const port = 3000

app.get("/products", (req,res) => {

    res.json(arr);
   });
 
    app.listen(port, () => {
       console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

А сколько объектов у вас в массиве? Рискну предположить, что постепенное появление обеспечивает браузер (либо плагин, отвечающий за красивый рендеринг json в браузере), т.к. слишком большой массив выводите.
Чтобы проверить, что причина не в коде, можно отключить плагин/сделать запрос через инструменты тестирования, например Postman.

Чтобы не было задержек при выводе больших объектов, используют паджинацию: данные из БД разбивают на страницы (диапазоны строк) и выводят в API и отображают на клиенте по частям.